# JQuery closest tag not working with input with name

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to find value of a hidden input tag and assigned to another one using JQuery. I used closest method because there are more than one field with the same name. Here is my code.

```
<div class="column mcb-column one-fifth column_column get-latest-price-btn">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix" style="">
    <input type="hidden" id="machine-name" name="machine-name" value="Single Chamber Vacuum Packaging Machines">
    <a class="paoc-popup popupaoc-button" href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="popuppaoc-modal-267">Get Latest Price</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-fifth column_column get-latest-price-btn">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix" style="">
    <input type="hidden" id="machine-name" name="machine-name" value="Tabletop Vacuum Packaging Machines">
    <a class="paoc-popup popupaoc-button" href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="popuppaoc-modal-267">Get Latest Price</a> </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.get-latest-price-btn').on('click', function(){ 
        var test    = $(this).closest("input[name='machine-name']").val();     
        alert(test);
        var machine = $('input[name="machine-name"]').val();               
        alert(machine );
        $('input[name="machinename"]').val(machine);
    });
</script>
```

The second alert function returns the correct value, but the first one returns `undefined`.

Comment: Use `.find()` instead of `.closest()` as `input[name='machine-name']`  is descendent of `div.get-latest-price-btn`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ vs https://api.jquery.com/find/ - Sometimes it's helpful to revise the docs.

Comment: @Satpal if more than one field has the same class, then which one will selected?

Comment: `$(this).find("input[name='machine-name']")` will return collection however `$(this).find("input[name='machine-name']").val()` will value of first element

Comment: @geeth `machinename` is not available in your HTML

Comment: @Ajith I know, it is placed in popup div and I didn't paste that code because it is not important in this issue

Comment: Closest will search up the DOM tree.  Find searches down the DOM tree.  There's nothing higher in your HTML DOM than the first button div so it will be undefined.

Comment: @NathanChampion Thank you. Now I understand what the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.get-latest-price-btn').on('click', function(){ 
    var test    = $(this).find('input[name="machine-name"]').val();     
    alert(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As `Satpal` and `NathanChampion` said, I changed closest() event to find(), then my problem solved.

```
 $('.get-latest-price-btn').on('click', function(){ 
    var test    = $(this).find("input[name='machine-name']").val();     
    alert(test);        
    $('input[name="machinename"]').val(machine);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the closest is not working because your element from which you have get value inside the click button block. you can simply use find function. ***Closest*** is working if the element outside the block.

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="column mcb-column one-fifth column_column get-latest-price-btn">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix" style="">
    <input type="hidden" id="machine-name" name="machine-name" value="Single Chamber Vacuum Packaging Machines">
    <a class="paoc-popup popupaoc-button" href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="popuppaoc-modal-267">Get Latest Price</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="column mcb-column one-fifth column_column get-latest-price-btn">
  <div class="column_attr clearfix" style="">
    <input type="hidden" id="machine-name" name="machine-name" value="Tabletop Vacuum Packaging Machines">
    <a class="paoc-popup popupaoc-button" href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="popuppaoc-modal-267">Get Latest Price</a> </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.get-latest-price-btn').on('click', function(){ 
        var machine    = $(this).find("input[name='machine-name']").val();     
        alert(machine);
       
        $('input[name="machinename"]').val(machine);
    });
</script>
```